# Get Reqeust fails with Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, get-request

I'm trying to send a get request to the server. But I'm getting the following error, any idea how to avoid the error?

the error:

> events.js:183
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ******
>       at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
>       at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)

my request:

```
var https = require("https");

// Update these options with the details of the web service you would like to call
var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https:*****',
  resolveWithFullResponse: true,
  json: true
};

var req = https.request(options, res => {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  var returnData = "";

  res.on('data', chunk => {
    returnData = returnData + chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('returndata: ' + JSON.stringify(returnData))
    var pop = JSON.parse(returnData).population;
    callback(pop);
  });
});
req.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to define request options to be passed to `https.request()`:

1. By specifying `hostname`, `path` and (optionally) `port` as separate request options:

   ```
   var options = {
     method: 'GET',
     hostname: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
     path: '/posts/1',
     port: 443
   };
   ```
2. By using creating an instance of [url.URL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_url):

   ```
   var URL = require('url').URL;
   var options = new URL('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
   ```

   For more information please refer to the official [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_url_options_callback).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, you can't set uri on the options object as such, you either use a uri string / URI object or you use the options object for this request type (see [Node.js http.request docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback))

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
    hostname: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    path: '/todos/1',
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    let returnData = "";

    res.on('data', chunk => {
        returnData = returnData + chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('returndata: ', returnData);
    });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});

req.end();
```